# Array of Children inside Context Provider

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a custom component that is structured like this:

```
          <Switch>
            <Component />
            <Component />
            <Component />
          </Switch>
```

I'm doing this because I have logic inside `<Switch />` that I want to then access through the child components.

I can easily render this as follows:

```
    return (
        {children}
    );
```

However when I add a context provider around {children}, I receive an error:

```
    return (
      <SwitchContext.Provider value={}>
        {children}
      </SwitchContext.Provider>
    );
```

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Switch`.
```

I've tried looping through the children array, but it didn't work.

Why is this happening and how can I make it work?

My components:

```
const SwitchContext = React.createContext;

  const Component = () => {
    return <>{"Hey"}</>;
  };

  const Switch = ({ children }) => {
    // Doesn't work
    return (
      <SwitchContext.Provider value={"a value"}>
        {children}
      </SwitchContext.Provider>
    );

    // Works
    return <>{children}</>;

  };
```

Comment: As the error says, `children` is undefined. You should use the React Dev Tools to debug this. If you still need help, then show a more complete example. Show the class and `render()` method that contains each `return` you show here. Then show the `render()` method of the parent component.

Comment: Added, both `Switch` and `Component`. They're as simple as they can get. Children isn't undefined so I'm unsure what could be causing it.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips to debug your code. In addition, be sure to install the React Dev Tools in your browser so you can inspect React elements and their props and state.

Comment: My app isn't rendering so I cannot inspect anything. I know how to debug programs, I'm just unclear on why this specific syntax wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the error message. Which exact line of code causes the error? Is it `<SwitchContext.Provider value={"a value"}>`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error complains that `SwitchContext.Provider` is undefined. That is because you assigned `SwitchContext` to the function `createContext` which doesn't have a `Provider` attribute. To fix the problem, you need to call the `createContext()` function instead:

```
const SwitchContext = React.createContext(); // Add parens here
```